# Recognizing all deprecated server tags

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-11

Is there a complete listing of deprecated IE11 tags such as "bgcolor" ?

This page did disp[lay them but it appears to have moved : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773181(v=vs.85).aspx (page is not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html

validate your markup at validator.w3.org/nu.... it will detect and report any depreciated ATTRIBUTES for your chosen doctype. eg... html4 has 'loose', 'transitional' and 'strict' system types.

Generally you should not use any 'presentational' attributes (height, width, align, background, color) and use CSS instead. eg. style="height:100px".

note also that spatial attributes are in px. width="100%" (invalid)... width="100" (valid)